What is the ideal way for a superhuman to carry a mortal?
There are a lot of varying methods, from fireman to bridal, for one grown human being to carry another grown human being. However, these are traditionally designed for normal humans, where the difference in mobility is usually along the lines of "can't walk" versus "can walk". What if the difference in mobility is more like "can walk" versus "able to leap tall buildings in a single bound"?
Frequently in fiction situations come up where supers have to carry a normal away from danger faster than the normal can run, or through an obstacle course of dangers the normal can't safely run and jump through. I'm curious about what method of carrying the normal would be most ideal when keeping the normal's physical limitations in mind.
If a superhuman needed to carry a normal human such that they could exert as much of their enhanced running and jumping ability as possible without injuring the normal human with the shock and/or whiplash, in what way should they be carrying said normal human?

In a pocket dimension, of course, where the acceleration is not experienced.  ("Not responsible for insanity, mutations, posession,or death caused by entering or exiting pocket dimension, or for asphyxiation while in pocket dimension; consult your physician, psychic, or exorcist for further details.")

@Jedediah Ooooh... I like the pocket dimension idea.

"Very Carefully"

Realistically, it’s impossible. No normal human can survive the rapid acceleration and deceleration of “leaping tall buildings” regardless of how they are held. Your internal organs, especially your brain, would be crushed in an instant. Humans just aren’t built to survive those kinds of forces.
If you want the best positions for humans surviving severe acceleration, take a look at fighter jet, race car, and rocket cockpits. The seats are designed to help the human pilots sustain high g-forces for somewhat extended periods of time. The harnesses are designed to maximize survival chances in the event of a crash (sudden deceleration). In summary: a sitting position with good neck support, and the acceleration force should only be in the forwards direction.

(picture from video by Randall Munroe)
It would be difficult for a (super) human to hold another human in this position. Ideally you’d put the regular human in a seat and then carry that seat. Failing that, put one hand on the back of their head to brace the neck and the other around the torso to hold them in place. When you jump, try to apply force by pushing your whole chest into the human’s back, maximizing the contact surface area to spread out the forces across their whole body. Before landing from your jump, flip around so the human’s back is towards the ground and use the same technique as before to spread out the forces. This will give them the best chance at survival, but the odds are still quite grim.
For reference, most humans can’t survive more than about 5-8 G’s of force for sustained periods of time. Trained humans can survive around 12. For sudden accelerations, such as in a car crash, about 20-25 G’s would kill most people. Trained humans with the right equipment have survived upwards of 50, with the record being somewhere around 200, but those are exceptional cases using top of the line vehicles and probably couldn’t be replicated by a superhuman holding someone with their hands.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Interesting to note that in one of the X-men movies, Quicksilver used the "back of the head grip" when running with Magneto

@quarague this one

Tactile Telekinesis rather than super strength
Superhumans are great for comics and cartoons, but if you want to bring physics into it... well, either physics gets unhappy or the superhumans (or bystanders) do.
Physics are spoilsports
That superhuman is lifting a building! (nope, he's holding some bricks from the corner he tried lifting, the rest of the building is slightly broken on the ground).
That superhuman is throwing a car! (nah, he's throwing the rear bumper at most. That thing came right off when he grabbed and pulled.)
So how could the two be brought together? By clearly dividing their responsibilities.
The technobabble solution: a no-physics zone!
"Tactile telekinesis" is one way I've read in a few places. Basically, their superhuman is not a super strong human (which would mean they act on the world through physics) - they are a tactile telekinetic! Which means their touch extends a telekinetic field over anything they do touch!
Telekinetic fields are clearly not physics, so we can let them do whatever we want. No physicist can point to a textbook that says "this is impossible"! So we can say "this telekinetic field protects his clothing from damage", and "it keeps things he's trying to lift in one piece" and "it also protects PEOPLE and animals he carries from harm!"
As soon as he stops touching the thing or person, the telekinetic field stops working - so physics gets its grabby hands on it again. Let go of a human a mile up in the sky? Physics says "gravity, get them!". Let go of an object you've accelerated? Inertia is here for you!
And the other way around too - grab a person falling from great height just before they hit the ground? Well, you grabbed them. Physics slide right off the telekinetic field, so that pesky inertia has to go stand in a corner while you enjoy the attention of the rescued damsel. No snapped necks for us!

This is a stated thing about Superman and his Marvel equivalent, Gladiator. They both use psychokinesis, not actual muscular strength. That's how he catches jets by their noses, and how he flew with Lois Lane by just touching fingers.

@RobertRapplean oh, that's the official thing for the poster child of superhumans? Interesting, thanks for that information! (any chance you remember where that was stated?)

Here's a good place to start: https://community.cbr.com/threads/just-finished-reading-byrnes-the-man-of-steel.94266/

I once read a webcomic where 'speedsters' had such a field, and could learn to extend it over people they touched to move them fast, that that was a talent that took training.  When a young speedsters attempts to move someone quickly without enough training in extending their field it ended up rather messily.  As in "lets collect all the pieces and hope their alien biology makes it possible to somehow piece them back together"

In wife-carrying competitions, the Estonian lift is generally felt to be the fastest for running in straight lines. This video compares the various lifts. There are other choices such as the fireman's lift if the person being carried is not conscious or cooperating.
If you are a Superhero, normal physics may not apply.

Awesome video! The controversial Dorking hold, I see. Yes.


faster than the normal can run

Reduce acceleration, not speed
Humans are fine going at high speeds. Concorde passengers sipped their champagne whilst zooming through the air at Mach 2. The first problem is the acceleration, or more specifically, the forces.
This shouldn't be too much of an obstacle. Humans are fine accelerating in any direction at 2g, and can handle short bursts of 10g (albeit probably not remaining conscious). Even at 2g, that's 20m/s/s. That's 72kph per second acceleration. Sustain that, and you're doing Mach 1 in 17s. If you need to burn at 10g, that goes down to 3.5s. Your super just needs to keep the acceleration reasonable.
What's the other feature of Concorde we're missing though? Well, the nicely aerodynamic fuselage. Unprotected human bodies aren't going to like this.  There's a reason you're careful with high-pressure air in workshops - and that still isn't very high pressure compared to this. You'll basically strip all the flesh off their bones, and then heat from friction will burn the bones. In essence, you'll need a reentry capsule to keep your monkey alive.

Acceleration is an important thing, but don't forget jerk (the rate of change of acceleration). Humans can generally handle a few G continuously, but going from 1G to 3G in a small number of milliseconds will probably kill you.

@Corey Sure - I thought about adding that detail too, but I decided it was enough to stick with acceleration for the basic concept. Even with a better S-curve on the movement, you can still go hellish fast if you don't have an upper speed limit.

Strapped to a stretcher.
This is similar to how injured people are transported to avoid jostling them and injuring them further. When the accelerations are much greater, you want to avoid jostling people which will cause injury in the first place. The problem with sudden accelerations is that different parts of your body try to move around relative to one another, and the only thing holding it all together is your own spongy flesh.
The superhero should strap down the person being transported, securely immobilizing them - it will be far preferable to having some straps holding your arms down rather than tearing your shoulder out of its socket, for example. Of course, this won't prevent internal injuries - you might prevent whiplash neck injury by immobilizing the head, but it won't keep the brain from smacking the interior of the skull.

Lots of answers pointing out why you really don't want to look too closely at the physics of superheroes, and they're all absolutely correct.
Now let me present you with the solution: Green Lantern.
Green Lantern is one of the only comic book superheroes whose powers can explain this sort of thing because his ring can - and routinely does - manifest inertial fields. When Lantern catches someone falling from a building, it's an inertial field that slows them down. When he travels with others to another planet he surrounds them in a shell that generates an environment and an inertial field. He can accelerate people at hundreds of Gs because they don't feel a thing.
And while Superman doesn't use a Power Ring, there's no question - in any world where physics isn't completly irrelevant - that his powers include the generation of inertial fields. When he picks up an ocean liner by the bow, he doesn't just tear off the front of the ship. When he catches a plane by grabbing the bottom of the fusilage, no ripping the plane to pieces. When was the last time he accidentally ripped the skids off a helicopter while catching it out of the sky?
And more importantly, when Superman stands at the bottom of the Daily Planet building and holds his arms out to catch Lois after she's fallen from the roof, she doesn't get chopped into 3 pieces and splatter all over the sidewalk. No amount of super speed handling is going to help there.
The answer is that Superman generates and controls extremely versatile and powerful fields of force, including inertial fields. This explains all of his strength-related powers, most of his physical invulnerability (his body is constantly surrounded by forcefields), his flight - including how he can stand unsupported in mid air - and how he can travel at mach speed with a person held in his arms without them dying from any number of high-speed-wind-shear-related nasties.
The good news is that inertial compensation is a mainstay of SF writing since way back, so everybody is already familiar with the concept. The bad news is it's not actually compatible with physics as we understand it... but you're already writing about superhumans, so that's probably not that important.

The problem with trying to crowbar superpowers (aka magic) into science is that science always wins
The simplest answer is: there isn't one.
All the effort put into protecting the human body in a modern high performance jet fighter against the acceleration of the jet and the rushing content of the atmosphere is in play. Why do you need a canopy? Because at those speeds the wind can tear flesh from the bone (heaven help you if something else is in the atmosphere, like dust or a duck) and both the seat and the suit is designed to keep the pilot from passing out or dying from the acceleration.
It's worth noting that while you can keep the neck (etc.) from moving to reduce whiplash, there comes a point where you can't keep the brain from moving, or the heart, or the lungs.... You can kill a person because of what acceleration is doing to the inside of a human being, not just the outside.
So, unless your super hero is going to package up the human in a suit and a seat with a protective bubble, they're forced to do what we humans with airplanes must do today: slow down. A lot.
Science vs. superheros. Science always wins.
Let's throw the majority of science to the wind... what could we do within the realm of suspension of disbelief?
Every position will have its pros and cons, which is why we generally don't like questions asking for "ideal" or best/worst, most/least, etc. because the circumstances of the story change the conditions. The best position for carrying a baby won't be the best position for an adult. The best position for someone obese won't be the same as someone skinny, nor the best for someone athletic vs. someone who isn't.
But an effective position that could be considered the go-to solution without knowing anything about the story could be the Face-In Position:
Image courtesy Infantino
This position protects the sensitive areas of the body (like the eyes) while minimizing the acceleration problems.
And since you, the author, are making a big deal about it (vs. the original authors of Superman, who just had Superman carrying Lois Lane like a bride over the threshold of a new home), you hope that your readers don't start wondering how realistic it all is.

This kinda sounds like a Rule of Cool answer :P

@TheDemonLord :-) I'm liking chai_tea's flying backwards idea better... hopefully he/she will put that in their answer rather than leave it in comments.

You may want to add the Rautek maneuver as an alternativek, as it does not require equipment. See https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/Rautek-maneuver.png/320px-Rautek-maneuver.png

@toolforger Technically the Face-In position doesn't require equipment. The image is showing the position using a baby because the place I found the list happens to sell baby equipment. An adult could hang on (theoretically). Frankly, if the superhero is hauling around a baby without adequate safety requirements, they should be ticketed by law enforcement in every jurisdiction they pass through. :-)

Pickle the human(s) in a jar
At least in theory, when human body is floating in water, it should be able to withstand much larger accelerations thanks to water supporting the body from all sides. There are limits as various parts of body have various densities, there are air bubbles in lungs,ears,etc. would result in potentially dangerous forces inside the body.
Let's assume it is feasible. In emergency, superhero would throw you in the jar, tell you to hold your breath, close the lid tightly so that water isn't sloshing and whisk it away to safety. If sustaining more than few seconds is necessary, there could be breathing apparatus inside. For humans who don't know how to swim or generally prone to panic in this situation and start drowning...well, it beats the alternatives.

Ideally you'd fill the lungs with highly oxygenated fluid (like PFC) to cushion the lungs from the inside. More pickle!

@Corey can you do that in a second or two? Presumably you want to get the "mudpeople" out of danger asap, without extensive preparations.

Yeah, that's a downside: it would take some prep. Not so useful for a rescue situation :(
